# Exception point from the beginning or from the end of the nickname

Tags: regex, string, url

I have custom [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/M5zyRn/1) for check facebook user nickname:

```
(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:facebook)\.com\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-\.]+)
```

How can I exclude a point from the beginning or from the end of a nickname?

**Example:**

```
facebook.com/john.doe   // correct
facebook.com/.john.doe   // uncorrect started with dot (.)
facebook.com/john.doe.   // uncorrect ended with dot (.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to replace the last part with `\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*$`.

That will match 1+ times a word character followed by a repeating group that will match 0+ times a dot and 1+ times a word character and assert the end of the string `$`

If there can be only 1 part with a dot following, than the `*` can be replaced by a `?` to make it optional.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67Fjwk/1/)

If it is not at the end of the string, you could use `\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?!\S)` using a negative lookahead to assert that what is on the right side is not a non whitespace character.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67Fjwk/2)

Note that `(?:facebook)` can be written without the grouping structure and the start could be written by just making the s optional `(?:https?:\/\/)?`. Depending on the delimiter you don't have to escape the forward slash.

Comment: I need a nickname separately. In your case, the weight returns the link with the site address. @The fourth bird

Comment: @AndreasHunter You could use a capturing group to get only the username [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/67Fjwk/3)